# Fetching for Strapi v3 is not working with Strapi v4

Tags: vue.js, axios, strapi

With Strapi v3 my code perfectly working:

```
  api.loadSource(async actions => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/events')

    const collection = actions.addCollection({
      typeName: 'Event',
      path: '/events/:id'
    })

    for (const event of data) {
      collection.addNode({
        id: event.id,
      })
    }
  })
```

But with update to Strapi v4 I'm getting the error: **TypeError: gridsome.server.js: data is not iterable (29:25)**

```
  27 |     })
  28 |
> 29 |     for (const event of data) {
     |                         ^
  30 |       collection.addNode({
  31 |         id: event.id,
```

I know, that now Strapi added /api/ to the path and also not showing relations by default. But this not fixing the situation:

const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/events?populate=')

output when enter in browser **http://localhost:1337/api/events/1**

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Coffe",
      "description": "We get together",
      "date": "2022-05-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "duration": 2,
      "price": 0,
      "createdAt": "2022-06-11T12:40:06.542Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-06-11T19:45:53.548Z",
      "publishedAt": "2022-06-11T13:05:10.375Z"
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    
  }
}
```

When enter **http://localhost:1337/api/events/1?populate=***

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Coffe",
      "description": "We get together",
      "date": "2022-05-30T22:00:00.000Z",
      "duration": 2,
      "price": 0,
      "createdAt": "2022-06-11T12:40:06.542Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-06-11T19:45:53.548Z",
      "publishedAt": "2022-06-11T13:05:10.375Z",
      "categories": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "Music",
              "createdAt": "2022-06-11T12:44:07.472Z",
              "updatedAt": "2022-06-11T12:45:32.721Z",
              "publishedAt": "2022-06-11T12:45:32.720Z"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You could start with debugging what data is, as it's obviously not an array. This is done on your side.

Comment: but why in Strapi v3 identical structure is an array?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing details, which weren't provided

Comment: Just added the details of the response from the browser.

Comment: I see what you mean. See https://github.com/strapi/rfcs/blob/v4/rest-api/rfcs/xxxx-v4-rest-api.md . You could possibly handle new response format in Axios interceptor to keep the rest of client code as is.